# Excel VBA : Hyperlink that fills target cell's contents with hyperlinked text

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

There are a lot of similar questions on here about VBA and hyperlink in excel, but nothing that I could modify to my own situation.

On one sheet I have a column of names (E:E), and on another I have a cell (D13).

What I want to do is hyperlink each cell in column (E:E) such that, when clicked, the hyperlink not only takes me to cell (D13) but also populates cell (D13) with the name that I clicked on.

So, click "John Smith" (Sheet1!E1) ---> (Sheet2!D13) = "John Smith"

Answer (score 3):

First you need a tiny piece of code in a standard module to install the hyperlink in `Sheet1`:

```
Sub MakeLink()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("E1"), Address:="", SubAddress:="Sheet2!D13", TextToDisplay:="Stuff"
End Sub
```

Then you need an event macro in the worksheet code area to do the content transfer:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    ActiveCell.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Target.Parent.Address).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I like your solution, doesn't involve using `.Select`, and actually does the requested hyperlinks.. kind of. `Anchor:=Range("E1")` should also be qualified(i.e.: `Anchor:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1")`), otherwise if ran from a different sheet it won't have the intended result. It also doesn't create links in `E:E`, but just `E1`... which should be easily rectified in a loop i guess.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I have discovered a problem. I can get it to work as intended but only for the first five to six names? After that it just returns the sixth name in Sheet2!D13. I have qualified the anchor, as mentioned above. Do you have any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution may be to use VBA. If you're unsure on how to do that, record s macro that selects a cell in e, then goes to D13 and updates its value, then look at the code that was recorded and use those snippets to create your code. At a high level you'd want to trigger a macro on click of any cell in column E that does something like:

`Dim e_value = <value of selected cell in column E>
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("name of sheet 2").Range("D13") = e.value
 Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D13"), Scroll:=False`

Note that the above contains pseudocode, but it should give you a general idea on how you could proceed.